# Couldn't match expected type ‘[Integer]’ with actual type ‘Integer’

Tags: haskell

I am working on creating a list of all the even numbers in the Fibonacci series which are less than or equal to 4,000,000. In Haskell, I've defined the Fibonacci series as:

```
fibs = 1 : 2 : next fibs
  where
    next (a : t@(b:_)) = (a+b) : next t
```

and am using the following list comprehension to construct my set:

```
[ x | x <- take 50 fibs, x `mod` 2 == 0, last x <= 4*10^6 ]
```

However, GHC is throwing a `Couldn't match expected type ‘[Integer]’ with actual type ‘Integer’` error.

I understand that the predicate, `last x <= 4*10^6`, is responsible for the error. Inspired by hammar's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16492431/2002447), my initial reaction was to ensure that `4*10^6` was the right type, so I tried rephrasing the predicate as `last x <= toInteger 4*10^6` to no avail; same error. I also thought that maybe I needed to specify `4*10^6` as a singleton (i.e. `[4*10^6]`), but no luck there either.

I'm struggling to understand what is exactly going on and how best to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> sum [ x | x <- take 50 fibs, x `mod` 2 == 0, last x <= 4*10^6 ]
> ```

`take 50 fibs` is a list of `Integer` (`[Integer]`), and `x` is an element of that list (thus an `Integer`). `last` is a function which takes a list...

```
GHCi> :t last
last :: [a] -> a
```

... but you are passing an `Integer` to it. You don't need `last` to filter the elements in the list comprehension; just use:

```
sum [ x | x <- take 50 fibs, x `mod` 2 == 0, x <= 4*10^6 ]
```

By the way, given that you know that the numbers in `fibs` always increase, you can write your expression as:

```
-- (<= 4*10^6) is shorthand for (\x -> x <= 4*10^6)
sum [ x | x <- takeWhile (<= 4*10^6) fibs, x `mod` 2 == 0 ]
-- Three equivalent alternatives:
(sum . takeWhile (<= 4*10^6)) [ x | x <-  fibs, x `mod` 2 == 0 ]
(sum . takeWhile (<= 4*10^6) . filter (\x -> x `mod` 2 == 0)) fibs
(sum . takeWhile (<= 4*10^6) . filter ((== 0) . (`mod` 2))) fibs
```

That way you don't need the arbitrary limit of 50 elements.

Comment: Awesome. My problem was thinking of `x` as a list. Appreciate the thoughtful explanation and bonus alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

```
fibs :: [Integer]
take 50 fibs :: [Integer]

x <- take 50 fibs
x :: Integer

last :: [a] -> a
last x :: ???
```

Your list comprehension will typecheck if you remove `last`. I think what you meant to write is something more like

```
[ x | x <- takeWhile (<= 4*10^6) $ take 50 fibs, x `mod` 2 == 0 ]
```

though.